# Yet another "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" issue

Tags: java, dictionary, foreach, cycle

I have this code that return a java.lang.iterable error. I know where i'm doing the error, but I don't know exactly how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
public class ManagementServiceHandler implements ManagementService.Iface {
    private Map<Node, Integer> nodes;
    private int portCount = 1025;

    public ManagementServiceHandler() {
      nodes = new HashMap<Node, Integer>();
    }

    //register node
    public int RegisterNode(Node hostAndService) throws TException {
        portCount++;
        nodes.put(hostAndService, portCount);

        return portCount;            
    }

    //get service
    public Map<String, Integer> getProvidersForServices(String svcName, int port) throws TException {
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Node, Integer> pair : nodes.entrySet()) {
            for (String nodeService : pair.getKey().serviceName) {
                if (nodeService.equals(svcName)) {
                    result.put(pair.getKey().serviceName, pair.getValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem lies in the second method, at the second foreach cycle. I'm not sure what should I put in the right part of the cycle, after `pair.getKey()`. What I want to do is cycling all the entries`<Node, Integer>`" inside the Map `nodes`, then write each entry of serviceName into the other Map `result`.

I know that the right part of the foreach statement represents the collection of elements through which I want to cycle, but this doesn't help me much in this case, besides the fact i'm coding that wrong..

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all you want is assignment to a local variable. Replace

```
for (String nodeService : pair.getKey().serviceName)
```

with

```
String nodeService = pair.getKey().serviceName;
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and Nemo that answered next, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap.Entry is just a tupel and not an iterable collection

It means that you don't need the second for-each, because you can accsess the Node.serviceName directly by

```
String serviceName = pair.getKey().serviceName;
```